# How to design and build application with Mono for android and MonoDevelop on linux ?

Tags: android, linux, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Does it exist any information explaining how to develop with mono for android on a Linux only workstation.

- Mono on Linux , **ok**
- MonoDevelop on Linux, **ok**
- android SDK on Linux, **ok**
- Mono for android on Linux, **not found** (only found Windows & Mac)

Does Mono for android limited on Mac and Windows development workstation. Or does it exist a trick to be able to use it on linux ?

Comment: ... love to see one day .. Xamarin studio for android on Linux ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono for Android only works on Mac or Windows.

Comment: Yeap, just got same answer from Miguel de Icaza. It's unsupported and there is no current plan to support it in the future.